# Update the date columns in iteratively manner

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table where I need to update the date fields: EFFECTIVE_DATE and EXPIRATION_DATE. I have 4 rows where for AGREEMENT_NO = 212132647 and OFFER_INSTANCE_ID=506412800

```
AGREEMENT_NO PARAM_SEQ_NO PARAM_NAME            PARAM_VALUES   EFFECTIVE_DATE               EXPIRATION_DATE      OFFER_INSTANCE_ID
------------ ------------ --------------------- -------------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------- 
   212132647    152507704 SDG primary CTN value 3095334348     10-JUN-2013:00:00:00 10-JUN-2013:00:00:00 506412800 

   212132647    152509361 SDG primary CTN value 3095334356     10-JUN-2013:00:00:00 10-JUN-2013:00:00:00 506412800 

   212132647    152509421 SDG primary CTN value 3095334350     10-JUN-2013:00:00:00 10-JUN-2013:00:00:00 506412800 

   212132647    152509464 SDG primary CTN value 3095328533     10-JUN-2013:00:00:00 10-JUN-2013:00:00:00 506412800
```

i want to update every effective_date and expiration date as below:

```
AGREEMENT_NO PARAM_SEQ_NO PARAM_NAME            PARAM_VALUES   EFFECTIVE_DATE               EXPIRATION_DATE      OFFER_INSTANCE_ID
------------ ------------ --------------------- -------------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------- 
   212132647    152507704 SDG primary CTN value 3095334348     10-JUN-2013:00:00:00 10-JUN-2013:00:00:01 506412800 

   212132647    152509361 SDG primary CTN value 3095334356     10-JUN-2013:00:00:01 10-JUN-2013:00:00:02 506412800 

   212132647    152509421 SDG primary CTN value 3095334350     10-JUN-2013:00:00:02 10-JUN-2013:00:00:03 506412800 

   212132647    152509464 SDG primary CTN value 3095328533     10-JUN-2013:00:00:03 10-JUN-2013:00:00:04 506412800
```

Is there any way where i can update these values directly like

```
update table1 set expiration_date = effective_date + 1/24/3600 where <somecondition>
and for next row: effective_date = old_exp_date + 1/24/3600 , expiration_date = effective_date + 1/24/3600
```

for all the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Very Simple.

You Have Just reached the destination.

You can follow this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1715a/2) or Below is the Update statement which you want.

```
update table1 set expiration_date = effective_date + 1/24/3600 where <somecondition>
and for next row: effective_date = old_exp_date + (1/24/3600)+rownum , expiration_date = effective_date + (1/24/3600)+rownum
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather brute force way by counting the number of records in the sequence:

```
update table1
    set effective_date = effective_date +
                          (select count(*) - 1
                           from table1 t2
                           where t2.agreement_no = table1.agreement_no and
                                 t2.expiration_date = table1.expiration_date and
                                 t2.effective_date = table1.effective_date and
                                 t2.param_seq_no <= table1.param_seq_no
                          ) / (24*60*60)
       expiration_date = expiration_date +
                          (select count(*)
                           from table1 t2
                           where t2.agreement_no = table1.agreement_no and
                                 t2.expiration_date = table1.expiration_date and
                                 t2.effective_date = table1.effective_date and
                                 t2.param_seq_no <= table1.param_seq_no
                          ) / (24*60*60)
```

Comment: @MithunKumarKulal . . . Out of curiousity, if this worked, why did you accept the other answer?